# CLang parse array in python. How it works?

Tags: python, c++, parsing, clang, llvm-clang

Defined array in C++:

```
int lea[6][6] = {(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0)};
```

With CLang I want to get something like this in python:

```
array = {'type': 'int[6][6]', 'name': 'lea', 'value': '(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0)'}
```

I know how to get the data type and name:
debug in pycharm screenshot - http://joxi.ru/a2XeWJGTy4VglA

But how to get the value - I can not imagine. Help me please.

**EDITED:**

I do this, but I think it's a crutch. It must somehow work smarter.

```
@staticmethod
def collect_array_from_node(node):
    """
    Из токенов узла собирает в словарь инфу о переменной
    Args:
        node: узел

    Returns: словарь

    """

    array_var = {'type': None, 'name': None, 'value': ''}

    array_var['type'] = node.type.spelling
    array_var['name'] = node.spelling

    tokens = list(node.get_tokens())
    was_sign_end = False
    start_value = False
    for tok in tokens:
        spell = tok.spelling.decode("utf-8")
        spell = spell.strip("\'\"\\")

        if tok.kind.name == 'PUNCTUATION' and spell == ';' and not was_sign_end:
            was_sign_end = True

        if tok.kind.name == 'PUNCTUATION' and spell == '{' and not was_sign_end:
            start_value = True

        if start_value and (tok.kind.name == 'LITERAL' or (tok.kind.name == 'PUNCTUATION' and spell not in '{}')):
            array_var["value"] += spell

        # выходим из цикла, если уже спарсились все необходимые значения
        if tok.kind.name == 'PUNCTUATION' and spell == '}':
            break

    return array_var
```

Screenshot debug panel in pycharm http://joxi.ru/GrqeYJ9TNG61Zr

Comment: What is this mysterious "CLang" you speak of? Is it related in any way go Clang?

Comment: I need to parse C ++ to Python. CLlang - this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @Kerrek Clang AST package provides source-to-source conversion. Not sure about the quality though.

Comment: @ДенисСуховерхов It is a nice question. I have seen that you had gotten the type of "int[6][6]". Would you like to share how to get the "[6][6]" part?